# Multiple Solution in single workspace

Tags: asp.net, tfs

we have 7 solutions in our TFS workspace , Data,Business,service, UI ...etc layers(solutions) .Everyone work on each solutions , but the problem is when we add any new method or reference in Data Layer solution, we need to call that reference(dll) in Business layer solution or other Layer solution and paste into our solution layer bin. this is manual process

how to call reference or maintain each and every time when new method or new classes are added and that need to call in other solution layer ? it should done automatically

regards,
rajneesh.

Comment: Why do you have a solution for each project? Normally, you would have one solution within it all your projects. You can then use project references that will automatically update on each build.

Comment: Properly using version control or a NuGet package store can help here, but you haven't supplied enough information to solve this issue. There are too many possible answers that will be too long.

Answer (score 0):

You can include the same project in multiple solutions.  If you really must have multiple solutions, I would suggest taking this approach.  Use a Project Reference instead of a binary file reference to reference the same project(s) from multiple solutions.

Or alternatively just have one solution with all projects.